# flow errors when a Component prop with a default value is wired up by react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, flowtype

using:

- flow 0.67.1
- react 16.3.1
- react-redux 5.0.7

Flow returns an type incompatibility error when a react component property, that has a default value, is wired up by react-redux.

The error is along the lines of:

> undefined [1](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-redux_v5.x.x/flow_v0.63.0-/react-redux_v5.x.x.js#L54) is incompatible with number [2](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-elementconfig).

Here is my code sample:

```
type MyProps = {
  myProp: number,
};

class MyComponent extends Component<MyProps> {
  static defaultProps = { myProp: 123 }
}

const myMapStateToProps = ({ someStateNumber }: { someStateNumber: number }): { myProp: number } => ({
  myProp: someStateNumber
});

const MyContainer = connect(myMapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

I think this has to do with the way the `connect` function is defined in the flow-typed [lib def](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-redux_v5.x.x/flow_v0.63.0-/react-redux_v5.x.x.js#L54).

```
declare export function connect<
  Com: ComponentType<*>,
  S: Object,
  DP: Object,
  RSP: Object,
  CP: $Diff<OmitDispatch<ElementConfig<Com>>, RSP>
  >(
  mapStateToProps: MapStateToProps<S, DP, RSP>,
  mapDispatchToProps?: null
): (component: Com) => ComponentType<CP & DP>;
```

The most relevant lines are:

`CP: $Diff<OmitDispatch<ElementConfig<Com>>, RSP>`

The CP generic param consists of component props that do not have default values ([doc on ElementConfig type](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-elementconfig)) less the properties handled by `mapStateToProps`.  OmitDispatch will also strip a prop with the name `dispatch` ... which can be ignored in this example.

and:

`): (component: Com) => ComponentType<CP & DP>;`

Which defines a ComponentType with props that consist of a union between the CP generic param and DP.  DP is the type of the optional second `ownArgs` param passed to the myMapStateToProps function. DP can be ignored because it isn't being used in the samples `myMapStateToProps` function.

In my example, this results in a ComponentType that doesn't have any props, because its only property has a default value.

I tried to play around with `$Diff` and `ElementConfig` on flow's web based try site and came up with [this](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQduANmugLICeAwiZAHZY+8LAA8YggCbpseGADoe4CAKEAeAN504cAhAgAuOHwCuIAEZYoAGi1wzyKIdQwowPgHM6AXwB8cTdrOyDDAuHASWATIxkwwAArEYOgAvP46eoYAjABMAMxWdg6GZAAWWExMEGRwXt4MMBxgWJgAynFwqerpBkamFlA19Np0DU1wACLABARYEgAqjc2pACST06oy+HIAokxYIIIwPHwEwO6qo1gQBHCcivyHPgUYbT4MAPTvcJbEUIzKzjg4mchjWM3miw6-i89DonzgYFYWFQ-z4gOQfAgMDKUDmyJgoKm4IWY063UM2UyuUGQA). I think that is the same issue.

For component's i author that should never be used without react-redux, the solution is to just strip out the default values, but what if that isn't always the case?  They may be 3rd party components or components that are used without react-redux.

What am i missing here?

Thanks!